# Pushing items to an array with multiple if cases in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to TypeScript and working on an Angular project.

I am making an API call and making few operations on the data received:

```
public data_Config: IConfig[] = [];

this.getService.Data(input).subscribe(
    data => {
        this.data_Config = data;
        this.data_Config.forEach(itm => { 
            if(itm.aFl == 'Y'){
                itm.Levels.push('A')
            }
            if(itm.bFl == 'Y'){
                itm.Levels.push('B')
            }
            if(itm.cFl == 'Y'){
                itm.Levels.push('C')
            }
        });
        this.dataSource_prgmConfiguration = new MatTableDataSource(this.data_prgmConfiguration);
        this.dataSource_prgmConfiguration.paginator = this.paginatorPrgmConfiguration;
        this.dataSource_prgmConfiguration.sort = this.sortPrgmConfiguration;
});
```

`IConfig` has several properties including 10-12 flag properties like`aFl`,`bFl`,`cFl`. Among the Flag properties which ever are true I want to add them to an array. I have done it in a simple way using if condition, but with 11-12 flags as many if conditions will be required, is there any better way to implement this?

#### Adding IConfig

```
export interface IConfig {
    TypeNm: string;
    aFl: string;
    bFl: string;
    cFl: string;
    dFl: string;
    eFl: string;
    fFl: string;
    gFl: string;
    hFl: string;
    PlaceHolder: string;
    Association: string;
    ActiveFl: string;
    Actions: string;
    AssociatedProgramsStr?: string;
    Levels?: string[];
}
```

Comment: A simpler way would be storing all the flags  and it's corresponding data which needs to be stored in a an object {aF1:'A',bF1:'b',...}. Then traverse the above object keys then if item has the key then insert the corresponding value from the object for the flag.

Comment: Please share the the `IConfig` definition

Comment: added `IConfig` definition

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
Object.keys(this.dataConfig).filter(key => key.indexOf('Fl') != -1).forEach(flag => {
    if(this.dataConfig[flag] == 'Y')
        itm.Levels.push(this.dataConfig[glag].charAt(0).toUpperCase());
}
```

this code is valid only if all your flags are with the same time of xFl where x is some letter and this flag refer to the same upper case letter that needs to be push to the Levels array.
a bit explanation:
first you extract the keys from your object that are flags, then you iterate on them and check your condition.

Comment: I get an error `vendor.js:77227 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` .

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways based on the requirement,

I'd assume `IConfig` interface has only `aF1, bF1, cF1 ...` boolean properties,
then you could something like following,

**Solution : 1**

```
  this.data_Config.forEach(itm => { 

      Object.keys(itm).forEah(key=>{
          if(this.data_Config[key] === 'Y'){
                itm.Levels.push('whatever'); // I don't know exactly what 'A','B' n all represent           }
      })
       
   });
```

**Solution: 2**

Let's say if `IConfig` interface has some other properties eg `height`, `width` some non-boolean, in such case you can do following,

```
const booleanProperties = ['aF1', 'bF1', 'cF1']; // define bool properties in array

this.data_Config.forEach(itm => { 

       Object.keys(itm).forEah(key=>{
           if(booleanProperties.includes(key) && this.data_Config[key] === 'Y'){
                 itm.Levels.push('whatever'); // I don't know exactly what 'A','B' n all represent           }
       })
           
});
```

Comment: I get an error `vendor.js:77227 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` .

Comment: `itm.Levels` is it array ? it should be array.

Answer (score 0):

In typescript you can create an `ENUM` like this.

```
enum enumVal {
  aFl  = 'A',
  bFl  = 'B'
}
```

Then on iteration check the value and add into your desired result.

```
result:any[] = [];
this.data_Config.forEach(key=>{
 if(this.data_Config[key] === 'Y'){
    result.push(enumVal[key]); 
 }
});
```